# minimum difference between sum of two subsets

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset

Folks,

came across a problem... found this intersting... am modifying it a little bit just tu pep it up.

> Given a set of integers (range 0-500), find the minimum difference between the sum of two subsets that can be formed by splitting them almost equally. (say count of integers is n, if n is even, each set must have n/2 elements and if n is odd, one set has (n-1)/2 elements and other has (n+1)/2 elements)
>
> sample imput : 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> minimal difference = 1 (subsets being 1 4 6 and 2 3 5 )
>
> sample input 2 : [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ]
>
> minimal difference = 0 (subsets being 1 1 2 2 and 1 1 2 2 )

is there DP approach for this problem.

Thanks guys...

raj...

Comment: Emphasizing: the OP is not interested in **building** the subsets, only in obtaining the minimum. Whether it's possible to do so without building the subsets is an open issue of course.

Answer (score 9):

This problem looks almost like the "balanced partition".

You can use a DP approach to build a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm that solves the balanced partition.  See problem 7 at http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/

It sounds like you could have a similar approach.

Comment: adl, yes by partitioning it into the two sets we shall know the balance... is there a way to find only the minimal difference without actually constructing the subsets...

Comment: @Rajan: Yes, there is a heuristic using a min heap to store the difference of the numbers in a loop until you're left with a single number. This way you can get the minimum difference possible. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#CITEREFKarmarkarKarp1982 for further info.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem recently using Dynamic Programming in c++. I have not modified the code to answer your question. But changing some constants and little code should do.

The code below reads and solves N problems.Each problem has some people (in your case number of integers) and their weights (integer values). This code tries to split the set into 2 groups with difference being minimum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_PEOPLE 100
#define MAX_WEIGHT 450
#define MAX_WEIGHT_SUM MAX_PEOPLE*MAX_WEIGHT
using namespace std;

int weights[MAX_PEOPLE];
//bool table[MAX_PEOPLE + 1][MAX_WEIGHT_SUM + 1]; 

bool** create2D(int x, int y) {
    bool **array = new bool*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        array[i] = new bool[y];
        memset(array[i], 0, sizeof(bool)*y);
    }
    return array;
}

void delete2D(int x, int y, bool **array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        delete[] array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
}

void memset2D(int x, int y, bool **array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        memset(array[i], 0, sizeof(bool)*y);
}

int main(void) {
    int n, N, W, maxDiff, teamWeight, temp;
    int minWeight = MAX_WEIGHT, maxWeight = -1;
    cin >> N;
    while(N--) {
        cin >> n;
        W = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cin >> weights[i];
            if(weights[i] < minWeight)
                minWeight = weights[i];
            if(weights[i] > maxWeight)
                maxWeight = weights[i];

            W += weights[i];
        }
        int maxW = maxWeight + (W>>1);
        int maxn = n>>1;
        int index = 0;
    /* 
       table[j][i] = 1 if a team of j people can form i weight 
                        from K people, where k is implicit in loop
       table[j][i] = table[j-1][i-weight[j]] if i-weight[j] >=0
     */
        bool **table = create2D(maxn+1, maxW+1);
        //memset2D(maxn+1, maxW+1, table);
        //memset(table, 0, sizeof(table));
        table[0][0] = true;
        /* for k people what can be formed?*/
        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            /* forming team of size j out of k people*/
            for(int j = min(k, maxn) ; j >= 1; --j) { 
                /* using j people out of k, can I make weight i?*/
                for(int i = maxW; i >=minWeight ; --i) {
                    if (table[j][i] == false) {
                        /*do not consider k if more than allowable*/
                        index = i - weights[k];
                        if (index < 0) break;
                        /*if without adding k, we can make the weight
                          limit with less than one person then one can
                          also make weight limit by adding k.*/
                        table[j][i] = table[j-1][index];
                    } /*outer if ends here*/
                } /* ith loop */
            } /* jth loop */
        } /* kth loop */

        maxDiff = MAX_WEIGHT_SUM ;
        teamWeight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= maxW; ++i) {
            if (table[n/2][i]) {
                temp = abs(abs(W - i) - i);
                if (temp < maxDiff) {
                    maxDiff = temp;
                    teamWeight = i;
                }
            }
        }
        delete2D(n+1, maxW+1, table);
        teamWeight = min(teamWeight, W-teamWeight);
            cout << teamWeight << " " << W - teamWeight << endl;
        if(N)
            cout << endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One good way to think about it would be, if you had a DP solution to this problem, could you use it to answer subset sum in a P amount of time? If so then your DP solution probably is not correct.

Comment: hmmm @Kevin bt we also need tu think of splitting it in equal parts, rite... so it can be partitioning as well... bt we are nw interested in the difference only..

Comment: If the integers are bounded (like range 0-500 as here) you can solve the subset-sum in polynomial time.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an instance of the [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-Complete.

According to the Wikipedia article, there is a pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this program in C++ assuming that max sum could be 10000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> VecInt;
typedef vector<int>::size_type VecSize;
typedef vector<int>::iterator VecIter;

class BalancedPartition {
public:
    bool doBalancePartition(const vector<int>*const & inList, int sum) {
        int localSum = 0,  j;
        bool ret = false;
        int diff = INT_MAX, ans=0;

        for(VecSize i=0; i<inList->size(); ++i) {
            cout<<(*inList)[i]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        for(VecSize i=0; i<inList->size(); ++i) {
            localSum += (*inList)[i];
        }
        M.reset(new vector<int>(localSum+1, 0));
        (*M)[0] = 1;
        cout<<"local sum "<<localSum<<" size of M "<<M->size()<<endl;

        for(VecSize k=0; k<inList->size(); ++k) {
            for(j=localSum; j>=(*inList)[k]; --j) {
                (*M)[j] = (*M)[j]|(*M)[j-(*inList)[k]];
                if((*M)[j]) {
                    if(diff > abs(localSum/2 -j)) {
                        diff = abs(localSum/2 -j);
                        ans = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mMinDiffSubSumPossible = abs(localSum - 2*ans);
        return ret;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BalancedPartition& bp) {
        out<<"Min diff "<<bp.mMinDiffSubSumPossible;
        return out;
    }
    BalancedPartition(): mIsSumPossible(false), mMinDiffSubSumPossible(INT_MAX) {

    }
private:
    shared_ptr<vector<int> > M;
    bool mIsSumPossible;
    int mMinDiffSubSumPossible;
    static const int INT_MAX = 10000;
};

int main(void) {
    shared_ptr<BalancedPartition> bp(new BalancedPartition());
    int arr[] = {4, 12, 13, 24, 35, 45};
    vector<int> inList(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    bp->doBalancePartition(&inList, 0);
    cout<<*bp;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    from random import uniform
    l=[int(uniform(0, 500)) for x in xrange(15)]
    l.sort()
    a=[]
    b=[]
    a.append(l.pop())
    while l:
        if len(a) > len(b):
            b.append(l.pop())
        elif len(b) > len(a):
            a.append(l.pop())
        elif sum(a) > sum(b):
            b.append(l.pop())
        else:
            a.append(l.pop())

    print a, b
    print sum(a), sum(b)
    print len(a), len(b)
```

Next step I would try to find a pair of numbers from opposite lists with difference half of the sums' difference (or close to that) and swap them.

Comment: l can have any number of elements, where every element is within the (1, 500)` range. If l is the (1,500) range the difference is either 0 or 1.

Comment: For [13, 59, 115, 175, 180, 214, 251, 317, 372, 416] this gives 2, but the right answer is 0: sum([13, 59, 251, 317, 416]) == sum([115, 175, 180, 214, 372]) == 1056.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't achieve perfect result.